# Output that looks like a triangle in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I wrote this program,

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int size = 5;

int row;
int col;

  for (col=0; col<size; col++){
    for (row=0; row<col;row++){
      printf(" ");
    }

    for (row=0; row <(size-col) ; row++){
      printf("*");
    if(col<=size){
      printf("*");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It should make a triangle like

```
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

But instead there is one extra * on every line. What is the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your use of the `col` and `row` variables is all backwards. I'm just pointing this out as you seem to be learning `C`.

Comment: damn really? I totally agree it seems silly to call them something that refers specifically to a row or a column when really they are just variables that help you change the number of spaces and stars. if you can elaborate i'd be very thankful. damn I'm really blown though I submitted it and I wonder if I'll get style points for it. thanks

Comment: @colle: I'd be more afraid of angering the Ancient Gods of Inconsistent Indentation from their Slumber.

Comment: Hey missingno, I never managed to catch you in Blue. One day... In all seriousness, I hope you're not referring to this program! The indentations seem legit to me, at least if its wrong I stayed wrongly consistent through the entire program. If there is a problem, tell me how I could improve. Thanks

Comment: @colle: Yes, the indentation of your program is ... sorry ... horrible. Anyway, what I meant by `col` and `row` was that you are iterating over *rows* in the outer loop, but you're calling the iterator variable `col`. Then, in the inner loop, where you iterate over the columns of one particular row, you call the iterator variable `row`.

Answer (score 2):

Mystical has a solution to the way you're printing two asterisks an iteration. Using the identifiers `row` and `col` in your example also makes things more confusing than just `i` and `j`, especially since the outer loop is actually your current row.

An alternative to your mess is (I'm hoping this isn't homework since it's not tagged as such):

```
int main(void)
{
   int size = 5;
   int i, j;

   for (i = size; i > 0; i--) {

      for (j = i; j < size; j++)
         putchar(' ');

      for (j = 0; j < i*2 - 1; j++)
         putchar('*');

      putchar('\n');
   }

   return 0;
}
```

You could also put `i*2 - 1` in a variable so that it's not calculated at each iteration of the loop (unless the compiler sees that you're not modifying `i`).

Comment: +1 for restructuring the program into a much more legible format too!

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
if(col<=size){
```

to

```
if((row % size) > 0){
```

will have the same effect too.

Answer (score 0):

How about printing the *'s like this

```
for (row=0; row<(9-2*col); row++)
  printf("*");
printf("\n");
```

This will print nine of the first row, seven on the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Factor your problem into relevant variables and give them meaningful names. This will improve code readability and make bugs easier to fix, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void triangle(int height)
{
    int row, col;
    int width = (2 * height) - 1;

    for (row = 0 ; row < height ; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0 ; col < width ; col++)
        {
            if (row > col)
            {
                putchar(' ');
            }
            else if (col < width - row)
            {
                putchar('*');
            }
        }
        puts("\r");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    triangle(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No one brought up recursion?  It's not quite pure because you have to track depth.  I called it a pyramid (pyr_) instead of a triangle:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

static void pyr_line(int depth, int nrows) {
    int i;

    if (nrows == 0) return;

    for (i=0; i<depth; i++)
            printf(" ");

    for(i=0; i<(2*(nrows-1)+1); i++)
            printf("*");

    printf("\n");
    pyr_line(depth+1, nrows-1);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    pyr_line(0, atoi(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```